# Rails routing sending non static default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am upgrading application from rails 2.3/x to 3.2.x

I have a old route like this:

```
map.calendar '/calendar/:year/:month', :controller => 'calendar', :action => 'index', :year => Time.now.year, :month => Time.now.month
```

rake routes generate something like this:

```
calendar        /calendar/:year/:month   {:controller=>"calendar", :action=>"index"}
```

I am not sure what is year and month here, are they default values being sent in case none is given? What would be its rails 3.2.x syntax.

I tried something like this:

```
match '/calendar/:year/:month' => 'calendar#index', :defaults => {:year => Time.now.year, :month => Time.now.month}
```

The route generated in rails 3.2.x is:

```
/calendar/:year/:month(.:format)  calendar#index {:year=>2013, :month=>9}
```

Help me out to convert this route correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `as` key to your `match` call:

```
match '/calendar/:year/:month' => 'calendar#index', :defaults => {:year => Time.now.year, :month => Time.now.month}, :as => 'calendar'
```

Comment: I did that as well and the route generated was

calendar        /calendar/:year/:month(.:format)  calendar#index {:year=>2013, :month=>9}

Why this hash is there, which is not in the case when route was generated in rails 2.3.x

Comment: @NaveenAgarwal was what?